# Finding duplicates in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates

```
SELECT COUNT(organization.ID)
FROM organization
WHERE organization.NAME IN (
    SELECT organization.NAME
    FROM organization
    WHERE organization.NAME <> ''
        AND organization.APPROVED = 0 
        AND organization.CREATED_AT > '2012-07-31 04:31:08'
    GROUP BY organization.NAME
    HAVING COUNT(organization.ID) > 1
)
```

This query finds duplicates, the problem is that it takes 6 seconds for the page to load because of the inner statement. Is there a way to make it run faster? MySQL database version 5.1.

Comment: Isn't the inner statement useless? `SELECT COUNT(organization.ID) FROM organization WHERE organization.NAME <> '' AND organization.APPROVED =0 
AND organization.CREATED_AT > '2012-07-31 04:31:08' GROUP BY organization.NAME HAVING COUNT( 
organization.ID ) >1)`

Comment: No. It will return a other result.

Comment: No , mine for instance returns 67 duplicates , your query breaks it down to 55,10,2 which adds up to 67

Comment: @SativaNL: the OP query is getting a count of all organizations that have a duplicate name, but ONLY for those organization names that have two (or more rows) with the specified predicates on APPROVED and CREATED_AT. The OP query will include additional rows in the total count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid `IN`.

```
SELECT COUNT(organization.ID)
FROM 
    organization
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT organization.NAME
        FROM organization
        WHERE organization.NAME <> ''
            AND organization.APPROVED = 0 
            AND organization.CREATED_AT > '2012-07-31 04:31:08'
        GROUP BY organization.NAME
        HAVING COUNT(organization.ID) > 1
    ) AS t ON organization.NAME = t.Name
```

Comment: This one is pretty fast, will test it later on again thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This is slow because MySQL is slow in processing "in" queries.  You can fix it by using this instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(organization.ID)
FROM organization o
WHERE exists (
    SELECT organization.NAME
    FROM organization o2
    WHERE organization.NAME <> ''
        AND organization.APPROVED = 0 
        AND organization.CREATED_AT > '2012-07-31 04:31:08' and
        organization.name = o.organization.name
    GROUP BY organization.NAME
    HAVING COUNT(organization.ID) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also find making indexes for the db fields included vastly improves speed in complex queries.

Comment: I think he has already indexes. The problem is the `IN` it will execute the statement for each row.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to return is a total "count" of all duplicates, but only for those organizations NAMES that have two or more rows with the specified predicates on APPROVED and CREATED_AT, then you could get by with an alternate statement to return an equivalent result:

```
SELECT SUM(c.cnt) 
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(organization.ID) AS cnt
           FROM organization o
          WHERE o.NAME <> ''
          GROUP
             BY o.NAME
         HAVING SUM(o.APPROVED = 0 AND o.CREATED_AT > '2012-07-31 04:31:08') > 1
       ) c
```

MySQL can make use of a suitable covering index to satisfy this query, otherwise, this is likely a full scan on the organization table. But it avoids referencing the organization table twice, and avoids a JOIN operation.

One suitable covering index for this query would be:

```
ON organization (NAME, CREATED_AT, APPROVED, ID)
```

Note that if the `ID` column is guaranteed to be non-NULL (either a NOT NULL constraint or its the PRIMARY KEY of the table, you can avoid referencing that column, and you can leave that column out of the index definition.)

```
SELECT SUM(c.cnt) 
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(1) AS cnt
           FROM organization o
          WHERE o.NAME <> ''
          GROUP
             BY o.NAME
         HAVING SUM(o.APPROVED = 0 AND o.CREATED_AT > '2012-07-31 04:31:08') > 1
       ) c
```

---

The EXPLAIN output shows this query using the index to satisfy the query without referencing any data blocks from the table:

```
id  select_type  table       type    possible_keys    key              key_len  ref       rows  Extra                     
--  -----------  ----------  ------  ---------------  ---------------  -------  ------  ------  --------------------------
 1  PRIMARY      <derived2>  ALL     (NULL)           (NULL)           (NULL)   (NULL)       2                            
 2  DERIVED      o           index   organization_ix  organization_ix  44       (NULL)      29  Using where; Using index
```